# iOS batch Images download finish and callback

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I have a batch images urls, I want to calllback a custom block when all image download finished.

And I use SDWebImage, the download image function is async, so how should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dispatch_group_t` to do this:

```
dispatch_group_t group =  dispatch_group_create();
for (NSURL *url in urls) {
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] imageDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:url options:SDWebImageDownloaderLowPriority progress:nil completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error, BOOL finished) {
        if (image) {
            // download success
        }
        NSLog(@"download...");
        dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
}

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"all download...");
});
```

Comment: There is no native way of doing this yeh? Also, just FYI this will change the order of the images.